# How to copy tortoisesvn settings from one machine to another

Tags: tortoise-svn

I want to copy **all** tortoisesvn related settings from one machine to another.  Where are these stored?

**Update:**

While some of the settings are stored at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN` as stated below, there are other settings that are not.  Comments seem to indicate these are Subversion specific settings as opposed to TortoiseSVN, but I cannot find where these are located.

Comment: You would really have better luck asking this on SO. Much more tortoise svn questions there & users who use it everyday.

Comment: @Idigas, SO is for **programming related** questions, this has nothing to do with programming, even though it is a tool used by many programmers.

Comment: I agree, I thought the questions was better suited for SU vs. SO.

Comment: Also @Idigas, the proper protocol is for users, such as you and I(who have 3000+ rep), to close questions that belong on SO and move them, not to have the user re-ask the question there.

Comment: @heavyd - Still learning the ropes here. If I vote for moving, along with 4 others it will get moved ? Won't just get closed with that reason in mind ?

Comment: @Idigas, that is correct, it will actually move the question to SO.  You can get a bit of question closing training here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance  :)

Comment: This is a Super User question.

Answer (score 6):

To save and restore the settings of TortoiseSVN you can use the following commands:

**Save:**

```
reg save HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tortoise.hive
```

**Restore:**

```
reg restore HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tortoise.hive
```

You can put each line in a separate text-file and save them as batch scripts, e.g Restore.bat / Save.bat

The settings will be backed up to and restored from the current user's desktop.

Comment: Run as admin and tack on the `\y` flag to avoid the prompt to overwrite, and you're good to go.

Comment: What about the credentials ? Also there?

Answer (score 6):

So the others are partially right, but you also have to export other settings from the registry as well, plus you should copy files from the Subversion AppData directory, so here are all of the places you need to pull data from after you have installed TortoiseSVN on your new machine:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN - Most Tortoise settings

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org - Global Ignores and Use commit times, possibly others

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseMerge - TortoiseMerge settings

C:\Users\{currentUser}\AppData\Roaming\Subversion - Any SVN global settings

Comment: Excellent. The only complete answer in the thread. I liked the Export Settings in the next answer idea, but it didn't really work right. Wouldn't import, and this did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

The TortoiseSVN [documenatation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html) shows an easy way to save/load the settings: `[Settings] -> Sync -> [button] Save settings to file | Load settings from file`

> #### Exporting TSVN Settings
>
> **Figure 4.91. The Settings Dialog, Sync Page**
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

From the source machine, export the settings from the registry at: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN`.  Then merge the .reg file on the destination machine(s).

Comment: This doesn't seem to include ignore settings and so potentially other settings in tortoise.

Comment: @user26453: the ignore settings aren't in the registry because they're Subversion settings rather than TortoiseSVN settings. They can be found in the svn "configuration area": http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html. Also see the "Subversion configuration file" *Edit* button in the TortoiseSVN general settings screen.

Comment: Clicking on the *Edit* button in the general settings screen pops up what looks to be a generic Subversion config, not at all showing what I currently have in the ignore field.  I will investigate where Subversion settings are stored via svnbook.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/command:sync` as described in the documentation of the [TortoiseSVN Commands](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics). It does the same as `[Settings] -> Sync -> [button] Save settings to file | Load settings from file` in @automatix answer:

```
set TSVN_CMD=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
set TSVN_SETTINGS_DIR=C:\path\to\your\settings\dir
```

**export** settings:

```
"%TSVN_CMD%" /command:sync /path:"%TSVN_SETTINGS_DIR%" /save
```

export settings including local settings:

```
"%TSVN_CMD%" /command:sync /path:"%TSVN_SETTINGS_DIR%" /save /local
```

**import** settings:

```
"%TSVN_CMD%" /command:sync /path:"%TSVN_SETTINGS_DIR%" /load
```

The settings file is named `tsvnsync.tsex`